# При нажатии на кнопку корневого элемента реализующего PageAdapter, выполнять контекст отображаемого фрагмента?

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager, viewpageindicator

Всем привет столкнулся с проблемой, буду признателен за помощь.
Есть фрагмент реализующий диалоговое окно. Окно содержит PageAdapter, который может листать вложенные фрагменты, всего их 4 шт(Главная,категория,фото,видео). У диалогового окна в шапке есть 
кнопка действий(при нажатию на которую в зависимости от текущего отображаемого фрагмента должна выполнятся некая бизнес логика, относящаяся к этому фрагменту).
Загвоздка с PageAdapter в том, что он за раз создает сразу два фрагмента, как я понял для ускорения анимации. А создать только один нельзя(игрался с setOffscreenPageLimit(), но толку мало). Покопавшись и инете нашел совет, мол вы в своих вложенных фрагментах реализуйте метод setUserVisibleHint, т.е предлагают определять отображается ли в данный момент этот фрагмент или нет. Я все сделал 
все работает но кривовато, при нажатии на кнопку действий для фрагмента "Категория", выполняется действие относящиеся к фрагменту справа "Фото", однако если покрутить pager туда сюда, то  через раз выполняется так как надо.

Вот мой код(чуть сократил чтоб легче было воспринимать):

Диалог:

```
public class DialogExercise extends DialogFragment {
private View rootView;
private ViewPager pager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private FragmentManager fragment;
public static LinearLayout llBtnAction;//Кнопка действий
private ImageView imgForActionBtn;
private SparseArray<Fragment> arr;


public static DialogExercise newInstance() {


    DialogExercise frag = new DialogExercise();
    // your code
    frag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.TransparentDialog);

    // your code

    return frag;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationSlide;

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

         setCancelable(true);
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exercise, null);


         //Кнопка действия
         llBtnAction = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.llBtnAction);


         fragment = getChildFragmentManager();
         pager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
         //Коллекция вложенных фрагментов(Главная,Категория,Фото,Видео)
         arr = SparseArrays.getSparseArrayTrainingExercisePagers();

         pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fragment,arr);
         //pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
         pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

         pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            }

         });


         return rootView;
   }




 }
```

Вот пример одного из фрагментов они все одинаковы:
Фрагменты идут в таком порядке (Главная,Категория,Фото,Видео)
При нажатии на кнопку действия, при отображаемом фрагменте "Категория", выводится Toast("Видео") фрагмента "Видео", для остальных все нормально.

```
public class TrainingsNestedMain extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
  private  View rootView;


  public static TrainingsNestedMain newInstance(int page) {
  TrainingsNestedMain fragment = new TrainingsNestedMain();

  return fragment;
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.d_exercise_nested_main, null);


  return rootView;
}

//Проверяем отображается ли этот фрагмент в данный момент или нет
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
   if (isVisibleToUser) {
       Log.d("MyLogs","Main - visible");
       //Регистрируем слушатель
       DialogExercise.llBtnAction.setOnClickListener(this);
     }else{
       Log.d("MyLogs","Main - not");
       //Удаляем слушатель
       DialogExercise.llBtnAction.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
}



 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.llBtnAction:
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Main", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     break;
     }
  }

 }
```

По логам в момент запуска получается вот:
Первый фрагмент "Главная"

```
11-02 00:38:25.280: D/MyLogs(5540): Main - not
11-02 00:38:25.280: D/MyLogs(5540): Category - not
11-02 00:38:25.280: D/MyLogs(5540): Main - visible
```

При переходе на фрагмент "Категория"

```
11-02 00:40:14.427: D/MyLogs(5540): Photo - not
11-02 00:40:14.427: D/MyLogs(5540): Main - not
11-02 00:40:14.428: D/MyLogs(5540): Category - visible
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит повесить OnPageChangeListener на ViewPager и в методе onPageSelected(int position) ставить нужный вам обработчик на кнопку действий в зависимости от position, я так понял кол-во элементов у вас фиксированое и порядок всегда сохраняется.

Comment: Да я могу так сделать, но тогда вся логика перенесется в корневой фрагмент, а мне кажется логика по нажатию на кнопку должна выполняться во вложенном фрагменте

Comment: @Eser, начнем с того, что у вас кнопка находится не во вложеном фрагменте это 1, что вам мешает передать колбэк в нужный вам фрагмент?

Comment: Для ускорения анимации page adapter по умолчанию загружает в память сразу два фрагмента, первый и следующий, следовательно на одной кнопке в текущий момент времени будет висеть два колбэка, а работать будет колбэк 2 го загруженного фрагмента, если бы page adapter загружал только один фрагмент за раз то проблемы бы не было. По этому я и пытался использовать метод определяющий какой фрагмент именно в данный момент выведен на экран. Кнопка общая, должна возвращать нужный колбэк, взависимости от текущего контекста(т.е фрагмента отображаемого сейчас)

Comment: @Eser, вы меня не поняли. Загружает в память несколько фрагментов вы правы, но в методе onPageSelected вы получаете Position, по которому в адапетере из массива фрагментов, вы можете получить нужный вам фрагмент и вызвать у этого фрагмета onClick передав туда view которую получили на вход в onClick в Activity. В каждом фрагменте в свою очередь обработать эту View.